# How to add terms and condition checkbox in my custom Checkout step in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

Hello I want to add terms and condition checkbox in my custom Checkout step , i refer the solution in stackexchange but no luck please guide me .

Answer (score 0):

Please check below blog for adding terms and condition.

[https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/terms-and-conditions.html#:~:text=Add%20terms%20and%20conditions%20to%20checkout%20page,click%20on%20Save%20Config%20button](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/terms-and-conditions.html#:%7E:text=Add%20terms%20and%20conditions%20to%20checkout%20page,click%20on%20Save%20Config%20button).

Comment: This blog is magento by default add checkbox for terms and condition in payment step but i want to add terms and condition checkbox in my custom step of checkout